# FileNotFoundException. How to construct a file path?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, io

I am trying create Scanner object, but I can't because FileNotFoundException: [**image link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQghF.png)

```
Scanner regionData = new Scanner(new File("RU.txt"));
```

Libraries

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: In your image the file lives in `C://RU.txt`. 
Did you try `C:/RU.txt` ?

Comment: IOException must throws or must be handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always surround this kind of error prone code in a try/catch block

```
Scanner regionData = null;

try {
   regionData = newScanner(new File("RU.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // handle what happens if exception is thrown
}
```

The file you specified needs to be in your root directory for the project.

Comment: Putting the scanner outside of the try block like this will allow you to access it beyond the scope of `try`; as opposed to @TeneCursum's answer where the scanner is declared inside the 'try', it will only be available to use inside that try block. Another thing to consider is that you will have to remember to close the scanner when done to prevent memory leaks by using 'regionData.close();'. You could alternatively use a try with resource block, declaring and initializing the scanner as a parameter to the try block, which will auto close it, but you run into the same scope issues there.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is '\' backslash as the file separator. Also this will require '\\' as backslash is an escape character in Java. It is smart to use File.Separator if this is meant for use not on your system as it will change depending on say Mac or Windows.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that your IDE (IntelliJ by the looks of it) is warning you that the code threw a FileNotFoundException. You should try wrapping the code in a `try/catch` block like so:

```
try {
    Scanner regionData = new Scanner(new File("RU.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle the error here. e.g.,
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, as mentioned by others, Windows uses the backslash ('\') as the file separator. Whereas UNIX systems use '/'.